# Debugging Python code

Tags: python, debugging

After a few days I still cannot figure out how to make this work on python (not an experienced programmer). Here it is the code pasted and at the bottom, the expected result:

```
color_list = ["red", "blue", "orange", "green"]
secuence = ["color", "price"]
car_list = []


def create_list(color_list, secuence, car_list):
    for num in range(len(color_list)):
        car_list.append = dict.fromkeys(secuence)
        car_list[%s]['color'] = color_list[%s] %num    
    return car_list
```

This is the result I want to achieve:

```
>> car_list
[{'color': 'red', 'price': None},{'color': 'blue', 'price': None},{'color': 'orange', 'price': None},{'color': 'green', 'price': None}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it all in one line for this particular scenario, assuming that `'color'` and `'price'` are constants.

```
car_list = [{'color': color, 'price': None} for color in color_list]
```

See [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) - it's a powerful tool.

---

If you also had a list of prices, `price_list`, you could do something similar:

```
car_list = [{'color': color, 'price': price} for color, price in zip(color_list, price_list)]
```

See the built in function [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

---

If the strings `'color'` and `'price'` are unknown at the time of execution (which I think is unlikely), you could do something similar to the following

```
car_list = [{secuence[0]: color, secuence[1]: price} for color, price in zip(color_list, price_list)]
```

Comment: what if I also wanted to asign something to 'price'? (what I want to asign to it is in a different list)

Comment: @BlenderUser the second section of my answer should answer that for you. If I have misunderstood what you mean, could you clarify?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly!! Srry

Answer (score 0):

Try the following I'm not sure your can use key addressing not but here I have used it.

```
def create_list(color_list, secuence, car_list): 
    for each in color_list:
        tmp = dict.fromkeys(secuence)
        tmp['color'] = each
        car_list.append(tmp)
    return car_list
```